# Fast algorithm to optimize a sequence of arithmetic expression

Tags: algorithm, optimization, numbers, set

**EDIT: clarified description of problem**

Is there a fast algorithm solving following problem?
<del>And, is also for extendend version of this problem
that is replaced natural numbers to Z/(2^n Z)?</del>(This problem was too complex to add more quesion in one place, IMO.)

### Problem:

For a given set of natural numbers like {7, 20, 17, 100}, required algorithm
returns the *shortest* sequence of additions, mutliplications and powers compute
all of given numbers.
Each item of sequence are (correct) equation that matches following pattern:

```
<number> = <number> <op> <number>
```

where <number> is a natual number, <op> is one of {+, *, ^}.

In the sequence, each operand of <op> should be one of

- 1
- numbers which are already appeared in the left-hand-side of equal.

### Example:

```
Input: {7, 20, 17, 100}
Output:
2 = 1 + 1
3 = 1 + 2
6 = 2 * 3
7 = 1 + 6
10 = 3 + 7
17 = 7 + 10
20 = 2 * 10
100 = 10 ^ 2
```

---

I wrote backtracking algorithm in Haskell.
it works for small input like above, but my real query is
randomly distributed ~30 numbers in [0,255].
for real query, following code takes 2~10 minutes in my PC.

([Actual code](https://gist.github.com/minkless/5451060),
 [very simple test](https://gist.github.com/minkless/5451090))

### My current (Pseudo)code:

```
-- generate set of sets required to compute n.
-- operater (+) on set is set union.
requiredNumbers 0 = { {} }
requiredNumbers 1 = { {} }
requiredNumbers n =
      { {j, k} | j^k == n, j >= 2, k >= 2 }
    + { {j, k} | j*k == n, j >= 2, k >= 2 }
    + { {j, k} | j+k == n, j >= 1, k >= 1 }

-- remember the smallest set of "computed" number
bestSet := {i | 1 <= i <= largeNumber}

-- backtracking algorithm
-- from: input
-- to:   accumulator of "already computed" number
closure from to =
    if (from is empty)
        if (|bestSet| > |to|)
            bestSet := to
            return
    else if (|from| + |to| >= |bestSet|)
        -- cut branch
        return
    else
        m := min(from)
        from' := deleteMin(from)
        foreach (req in (requiredNumbers m))
            closure (from' + (req - to)) (to + {m}) 

-- recoverEquation is a function converts set of number to set of equation.
-- it can be done easily.
output = recoverEquation (closure input {})
```

### Additional Note:

Answers like

- There isn't a fast algorithm, because...
- There is a heuristic algorithm, it is...

are also welcomed. Now I'm feeling that there is no fast and exact algorithm...

Answer #1 can be used as a heuristic, I think.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask. Perhaps you can use the fact that all your operations are increasing, and so is the partially computed sequence of numbers

Comment: thanks Basile. Should I delete this post before posting question at there, or leave here as a pointer?

Comment: Perhaps with using Prolog you could get better results for the backtrack. Otherwise I don't think that there is an algorithmical solution.

Comment: @viercc I disagree, Stack Overflow is a great place for this

Comment: Why does your output also solve for numbers not part of your input? Can you please elaborate on what needs to be done?

Comment: @IVlad I edited the question. In output, each numbers used by operator shoud be 1 or already computed number.

Comment: @GaborSch, I agree, the answer is "no", in my opinion there isn't a fast algorithm. The search space suffers from combinatorial explosion, whether you go forward from "1" or backwards from the input. There doesn't seem to be any way to sensibly cut down on the search space, e.g. how would you come up with some sensible "distance" metric for an algorithm such as A* search. It would however be interesting to try solving a simpler problem first, e.g. only addition, or only multiplication, and see if anything arises from that.

Comment: @GaborSch, TooTone, Thank you for suggesting Prolog. But I have no experience of Prolog, so I can't try that immediately. If there isn't a fast algorithm, I will use some heuristics as a last resort.

Comment: Can the routes to get to any number up to 255 can be precalculated? and then just look for routes with the most overlap or that require the same numbers to be produced

Answer (score 2):

What if you worked backwards from the highest number in a sorted input, checking if/how to utilize the smaller numbers (and numbers that are being introduced) in its construction?

For example, although this may not guarantee the shortest sequence...

```
input: {7, 20, 17, 100}

(100) = (20) * 5 => 
(7) = 5 + 2      => 
(17) = 10 + (7)  =>
(20) = 10 * 2    =>
10 = 5 * 2       =>
5 = 3 + 2        =>
3 = 2 + 1        =>
2 = 1 + 1
```

Comment: Let me confirm that your idea is "when I choose one from many ways to calculate desired number (e.g. 100), I do not need to choose not utilizing one (e.g. I may ignore 100 = 85+15 case)"?  If that is valid way to get shortest output, speeds up very much. But I can't prove it is valid.

Comment: @viercc yes, I'm not sure if it can be arranged to guarantee the shortest sequence..it was just an idea/direction to consider/test/possibly utilize.

Answer (score 2):

What I recommend is to transform it into some kind of graph shortest path algorithm.

- For each number, you compute (and store) the *shortest* path of operations. Technically one step is enough: For each number you can store the operation and the two operands (left and right, because power operation is not commutative), and also the weight (**"nodes"**)
- Initially you register `1` with the weight of zero
- Every time you register a new number, you have to generate all calculations with that  number (all additions, multiplications, powers) with all already-registered numbers. (**"edges"**)

  - Filter for the calculations: it the result of the calculation is already registered, you shouldn't store that, because there is an easier way to get to that number
  - Store only 1 operation for the commutative ones (1+2=2+1)
  - Prefilter the power operation because that may even cause overflow
- You have to order this list to the shortest sum path (**weight of the edge**). Weight = (weight of operand1) + (weight of operand2) + (1, which is the weight of the operation)

  - You can exclude all resulting numbers which are greater than the maximum number that we have to find (e.g. if we found 100 already, anything greater that 20 can be excluded)  - this can be refined so that you can check the members of the operations also.
- If you hit one of your target numbers, then you found the shortest way of calculating *one* of your target numbers, you have to restart the generations:

  - Recalculate the maximum of the target numbers
  - Go back on the paths of the currently found number, set their weight to 0 (they will be *given* from now on, because their cost is already paid)
  - Recalculate the weight for the operations in the generation list, because the source operand weight may have been changed (this results reordering at the end) - here you can exclude those where either operand is greater than the new maximum
- If all the numbers are hit, then the search is over

You can build your expression using the "backlinks" (operation, left and right operands) for each of your target numbers.

The main point is that we always keep our eye on the target function, which is that **the total number of operation must be the minimum possible**. In order to get this, we always calculate the shortest path to a certain number, then considering that number (and all the other numbers on the way) as given numbers, then extending our search to the remaining targets.

Theoretically, this algorithm processes (registers) each numbers only once. Applying the proper filters cuts the unnecessary branches, so nothing is calculated twice (except the weights of the in-queue elements)

Comment: I ran this algorithm in my hand & my head at [here(Gist)](https://gist.github.com/minkless/5449111). If I didn't make a mistake, this algorithm is incomplete.

Comment: @viercc I discovered one flaw, which is: if you're using `2=1+1` twice in an expression, you shouldn't take its weight twice. So, instead of `[3]4=1+3 [4]5=2+3 [5]6=3+3` I expected `[3]4=1+3 [3]5=2+3 [3]6=3+3`. I need to reconsider how the weights are calculated, but need some time for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & checking it. My consideration on your answer: if there is a weighting method, it should be able to distinct the cases of `input=20=(1+4)*4` and `input=15=(2+3)*3`. The weights of `5=1+4` and `5=2+3` necessarily **change depending on what the input is**. If input is `{20}`, `5=1+4` should have smaller weight than `5=2+3`, and so on. I think `21=7*3=(4+3)*3`, `28=(3+4)*4` and `35=(2+5)*5` have similar relation on them, and there's many other example, though I haven't confirmed yet.

Comment: @viercc Just to confirm the main goal: we should achieve the *least number of operations* which will produce *all input target numbers*. Is it correct?

Comment: @viercc I think that the number `5` has one minimal weight, and a set of number that are used to get there. If my assumption is correct, then we need to optimize the *aggregated set of numbers* used to achieve the goal. I am thinking that we should reconsider the problem. In your example, `5=[3]{1,2,4}` (calculated from  5=1+4=1+2*2=1+(1+1)*(1+1) ) or, `5=[]{1,2,3}` (calculated from  5=2+3=(1+1)+(1+2)=(1+1)+(1+(1+1)) ) -- it is not obvious which one you will choose. For `15=[4]{1,2,3,5}` is better (as 15=3*5), for `20=[4]{1,2,4,5}` (as 20=4*5) is the better.

Comment: @viercc So, we have a few choices for each number, and they can be even combined. Everything depends on the final target set. My guess is that 1. First we have to generate all the possible options (there are obvious cuts, e.g. 5=(((1+1)+1)+1)+1) generates `5=[4]{1,2,3,4}` which is worse than the other 2 combinations) 2. Second we have to investigate the resulting AND/OR graph, to find the least required set of numbers.

Comment: @viercc Actually, you can check the cartesian product for the possible sets of the target numbers (e.g. `5` has 2 sets, {1,2,3} and {1,2,5}), `6` has 1 set of {1,2,3}, 8 has 2 sets of {1,2,4} and {1,2,3} - so you have 2x1x2 choices. Find the least subset, and you got the solution.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to minimize the number of operations, but the problem _I_ have to solve is the efficiency of the algorithm. In that example, what I tried to say was: when we encounter the _not obvious_ case (e.g. `5`), we have to do depth-first search (=try both selection and select better way in the result) or apply any other search. I think it is as slow as my current code, so I thought "_If_ there was a method calculates a weight _which always makes correct choice_" and stated condition of such weighting method, I didn't know its existence.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my comment reading your first 2 comment only. Pre-calculating all the possible options and excluding not minimal set seems to be a good idea.

Comment: @viercc I see. But actually there is no optimal way, or better or worse choice *for a single number*, because our goal function was defined for *all inputs*. That's why this weight is not the best choice, and that's why there is no method that *always makes the best choice*. The latest algorithm I proposed will first *generate* all the possibilities, and in the second step you will have to choose the best of all the possibilities.

Comment: @viercc Since this requires comparison of sets of integers, to speed up the calculation, I would introduce a IntMap class, that would store the bits in an array of `long` or similar types. You can define the `and` `or` operations and `setBit()` `isSubset()` methods. That will speed up the calculations.